# What is the marginal log-likelihood in a Multi-Head Model?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language

I have to study the model described [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.13375.pdf). Given a passage text and a question about it, the model tries to find the correct answer to the question.

This model follows a multi-head approach: each head is a small module that takes the contextualized representations (coming out from BERT or RoBERTa) as input and computes a probability distribution over answers. Thus, the model probability for an answer is a weighted sum on every head. I made a diagram of how I suppose this model works:

[image: model diagram]

Even if the model describes the training loss function used for every single module, there is no clue about an overall training loss.

Checking the official implementation [code](https://github.com/eladsegal/tag-based-multi-span-extraction/blob/master/src/models/multi_head_model.py) (full repository [here](https://github.com/eladsegal/tag-based-multi-span-extraction)), I see that the loss refers to something called marginal_log_likelihood. Unfortunately, I don't know what does it means, and the paper does not mention it.

What is the marginal log-likelihood? How does it work in a model like this?

Comment: The paper does mention it—bottom of §3.2